# Get unique value from mutiple forms that have radio buttons - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a trivia game for a job interview and so far i've created a loop that populates forms with radio buttons for multiple choices.

The problem I'm having is a score counter. I need to only count the correct responses, preferably on click per form. Right now when I select an answer and then click any other answer it adds to the score because at least one correct answer is selected,

#### HTML

```
<div id="trivia">
    <form class='card0'>
       <text>Question</text>
       <input type="radio" id="Answer" value="correct" name="question0">
       <label for="Answer">Answer</label>
       <input type="radio" id="Wrong" value="incorrect" name="question0">
       <label for="Answer">Wrong</label>
    </form>
    <form class='card1'>
       <text>Question</text>
       <input type="radio" id="Answer" value="correct" name="question1">
       <label for="Answer">Answer</label>
       <input type="radio" id="Wrong" value="incorrect" name="question1">
       <label for="Answer">Wrong</label>
    </form>
</div>
```

#### jQuery

```
 for(j=0;j<21;j++){
        var score = 0;
        $('.card' + j + ' input').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var radioVal = $('input[value=correct]').val();
            if(radioVal){
                score+=1
                console.log(score)
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tips**

- make sure all your elements have unique ids
- wrap the radio buttons with the labels, it is easier and cleaner
- use event delegation, by assigning the event handler at the div level, rather than to every radio button
- you can probably use a single form element

```js
$('#trivia').on('click', e => {
  let div = $("#trivia");
  let rbs = div.find('input[type="radio"][value="correct"]');
  let rbsChecked = 0;
  $(rbs).each((i, e) => {
    if (e.checked)
      rbsChecked++;
  });
  $("#score").text(rbsChecked + "/" + rbs.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="trivia">
  <form class='card0'>
    <text>Question</text>
    <label><input type="radio" id="Answer0" value="correct" name="question0">Answer</label>
    <label><input type="radio" id="Wrong0" value="incorrect" name="question0">Wrong</label>
  </form>
  <form class='card1'>
    <text>Question</text>
    <label><input type="radio" id="Answer1" value="correct" name="question1">Answer</label>
    <label><input type="radio" id="Wrong1" value="incorrect" name="question1">Wrong</label>
  </form>
</div>
<output id="score"></output>
```

Good luck